Gutenberg Static blocks: viewScript doesn't import css for frontend?
I am building static block slider (Swiper JS). Used wordpress/create-block https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-create-block/.
Besides importing the JS & CSS files with `”viewScript”:
"viewScript": "file:./view.js"
i still need to enqueue the JS & CSS files with php like the old ways. If i don’t enqueue assets then the block won’t work on frontend.Why does this happen with a static block ? Isn't viewScript supposed to handle this ?
This is my view.js file :
import Swiper from 'swiper';
import { Autoplay, Keyboard, Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar } from 'swiper/modules';

// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import 'swiper/css/scrollbar';

// import styles bundle
import 'swiper/css/bundle';

// import "./styles.css";

// This should only be output on the frontend of the site - NOT the editor

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {

        // configure Swiper to use modules
        modules: [Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay, Keyboard, Scrollbar],

        // Optional parameters
        direction: 'horizontal',
        autoplay: {
            delay: 2000,
        },
        loop: true,

        // If we need pagination
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
        },

        // Navigation arrows
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },

        // And if we need scrollbar
        scrollbar: {
            el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
        },
    });
})

This is my block.json file :
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 3,
    "name": "m/simple-slider",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "Horizontal slider.",
    "category": "gutenberg-blocks",
    "icon": "slides",
    "description": "A simple slider",
    "attributes": {
        "images": {
            "type": "array",
            "default": []
        }
    },
    "example": {
        "attributes": {
            "preview" : true
        }
    },
    "supports": {
        "html": true,
        "color": {
            "background": true,
            "text": true
        },
        "spacing": {
            "padding": true,
            "margin": true
        },
        "anchor": true,
        "align": true
    },
    "textdomain": "simple-slider",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css",
    "viewScript": "file:./view.js"
}

And this is how i enqueue via php :
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'm_gsbp_enqueue_swiper_styles');

function m_gsbp_enqueue_swiper_styles()
{

    // Enqueue Swiper library JS
    wp_enqueue_script('swiper-js', 'https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js', array(), '6.8.4', true);

    // Enqueue Swiper library CSS
    wp_enqueue_style('swiper-css', 'https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css', array(), '6.8.4');
}

Am i doing something wrong or this is the intended behavior ?

I didn't declare the viewStyle for frontend and thus the css wasn't being enqueued.
{ "viewStyle": [ "file:./view.css", "example-view-style" ] }
build/view.css had all the needed css for swiper - it just wasn't being declared with viewStyle https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/#view-style .
view.css:
/*!*******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************!*\
  !*** css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].use[2]!./node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.css ***!
  \*******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/
/**
 * Swiper 11.0.7
 * Most modern mobile touch slider and framework with hardware accelerated transitions
 * https://swiperjs.com
 *
 * Copyright 2014-2024 Vladimir Kharlampidi
 *
 * Released under the MIT License
 *
 * Released on: February 27, 2024
 */

/* FONT_START */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'swiper-icons';
  src: url("data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64, 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");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
/* FONT_END */
:root {
  --swiper-theme-color: #007aff;
  /*
  --swiper-preloader-color: var(--swiper-theme-color);
  --swiper-wrapper-transition-timing-function: initial;
  */
}
:host {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
.swiper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  /* Fix of Webkit flickering */
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
}
.swiper-vertical > .swiper-wrapper {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.swiper-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-timing-function: var(--swiper-wrapper-transition-timing-function, initial);
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.swiper-android .swiper-slide,
.swiper-ios .swiper-slide,
.swiper-wrapper {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
}
.swiper-horizontal {
  touch-action: pan-y;
}
.swiper-vertical {
  touch-action: pan-x;
}
.swiper-slide {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition-property: transform;
  display: block;
}
.swiper-slide-invisible-blank {
  visibility: hidden;
}
/* Auto Height */
.swiper-autoheight,
.swiper-autoheight .swiper-slide {
  height: auto;
}
.swiper-autoheight .swiper-wrapper {
  align-items: flex-start;
  transition-property: transform, height;
}
.swiper-backface-hidden .swiper-slide {
  transform: translateZ(0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
/* 3D Effects */
.swiper-3d.swiper-css-mode .swiper-wrapper {
  perspective: 1200px;
}
.swiper-3d .swiper-wrapper {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.swiper-3d {
  perspective: 1200px;
}
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide,
.swiper-3d .swiper-cube-shadow {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
/* CSS Mode */
.swiper-css-mode > .swiper-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  /* For Firefox */
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  /* For Internet Explorer and Edge */
}
.swiper-css-mode > .swiper-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.swiper-css-mode > .swiper-wrapper > .swiper-slide {
  scroll-snap-align: start start;
}
.swiper-css-mode.swiper-horizontal > .swiper-wrapper {
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}
.swiper-css-mode.swiper-vertical > .swiper-wrapper {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
.swiper-css-mode.swiper-free-mode > .swiper-wrapper {
  scroll-snap-type: none;
}
.swiper-css-mode.swiper-free-mode > .swiper-wrapper > .swiper-slide {
  scroll-snap-align: none;
}
.swiper-css-mode.swiper-centered > .swiper-wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  flex-shrink: 0;
  order: 9999;
}
.swiper-css-mode.swiper-centered > .swiper-wrapper > .swiper-slide {
  scroll-snap-align: center center;
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
}
.swiper-css-mode.swiper-centered.swiper-horizontal > .swiper-wrapper > .swiper-slide:first-child {
  margin-inline-start: var(--swiper-centered-offset-before);
}
.swiper-css-mode.swiper-centered.swiper-horizontal > .swiper-wrapper::before {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  width: var(--swiper-centered-offset-after);
}
.swiper-css-mode.swiper-centered.swiper-vertical > .swiper-wrapper > .swiper-slide:first-child {
  margin-block-start: var(--swiper-centered-offset-before);
}
.swiper-css-mode.swiper-centered.swiper-vertical > .swiper-wrapper::before {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1px;
  height: var(--swiper-centered-offset-after);
}
/* Slide styles start */
/* 3D Shadows */
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 10;
}
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
.swiper-lazy-preloader {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -21px;
  margin-top: -21px;
  z-index: 10;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 4px solid var(--swiper-preloader-color, var(--swiper-theme-color));
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top-color: transparent;
}
.swiper:not(.swiper-watch-progress) .swiper-lazy-preloader,
.swiper-watch-progress .swiper-slide-visible .swiper-lazy-preloader {
  animation: swiper-preloader-spin 1s infinite linear;
}
.swiper-lazy-preloader-white {
  --swiper-preloader-color: #fff;
}
.swiper-lazy-preloader-black {
  --swiper-preloader-color: #000;
}
@keyframes swiper-preloader-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
/* Slide styles end */
.swiper-virtual .swiper-slide {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.swiper-virtual.swiper-css-mode .swiper-wrapper::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.swiper-virtual.swiper-css-mode.swiper-horizontal .swiper-wrapper::after {
  height: 1px;
  width: var(--swiper-virtual-size);
}
.swiper-virtual.swiper-css-mode.swiper-vertical .swiper-wrapper::after {
  width: 1px;
  height: var(--swiper-virtual-size);
}
:root {
  --swiper-navigation-size: 44px;
  /*
  --swiper-navigation-top-offset: 50%;
  --swiper-navigation-sides-offset: 10px;
  --swiper-navigation-color: var(--swiper-theme-color);
  */
}
.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-button-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--swiper-navigation-top-offset, 50%);
  width: calc(var(--swiper-navigation-size) / 44 * 27);
  height: var(--swiper-navigation-size);
  margin-top: calc(0px - (var(--swiper-navigation-size) / 2));
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: var(--swiper-navigation-color, var(--swiper-theme-color));
}
.swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-disabled,
.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-disabled {
  opacity: 0.35;
  cursor: auto;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-hidden,
.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: auto;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.swiper-navigation-disabled .swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-navigation-disabled .swiper-button-next {
  display: none !important;
}
.swiper-button-prev svg,
.swiper-button-next svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: contain;
     object-fit: contain;
  transform-origin: center;
}
.swiper-rtl .swiper-button-prev svg,
.swiper-rtl .swiper-button-next svg {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-rtl .swiper-button-next {
  left: var(--swiper-navigation-sides-offset, 10px);
  right: auto;
}
.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-rtl .swiper-button-prev {
  right: var(--swiper-navigation-sides-offset, 10px);
  left: auto;
}
.swiper-button-lock {
  display: none;
}
/* Navigation font start */
.swiper-button-prev:after,
.swiper-button-next:after {
  font-family: swiper-icons;
  font-size: var(--swiper-navigation-size);
  text-transform: none !important;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-variant: initial;
  line-height: 1;
}
.swiper-button-prev:after,
.swiper-rtl .swiper-button-next:after {
  content: 'prev';
}
.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-rtl .swiper-button-prev {
  right: var(--swiper-navigation-sides-offset, 10px);
  left: auto;
}
.swiper-button-next:after,
.swiper-rtl .swiper-button-prev:after {
  content: 'next';
}
/* Navigation font end */
:root {
  /*
  --swiper-pagination-color: var(--swiper-theme-color);
  --swiper-pagination-left: auto;
  --swiper-pagination-right: 8px;
  --swiper-pagination-bottom: 8px;
  --swiper-pagination-top: auto;
  --swiper-pagination-fraction-color: inherit;
  --swiper-pagination-progressbar-bg-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  --swiper-pagination-progressbar-size: 4px;
  --swiper-pagination-bullet-size: 8px;
  --swiper-pagination-bullet-width: 8px;
  --swiper-pagination-bullet-height: 8px;
  --swiper-pagination-bullet-border-radius: 50%;
  --swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-color: #000;
  --swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-opacity: 0.2;
  --swiper-pagination-bullet-opacity: 1;
  --swiper-pagination-bullet-horizontal-gap: 4px;
  --swiper-pagination-bullet-vertical-gap: 6px;
  */
}
.swiper-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 300ms opacity;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 10;
}
.swiper-pagination.swiper-pagination-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
.swiper-pagination-disabled > .swiper-pagination,
.swiper-pagination.swiper-pagination-disabled {
  display: none !important;
}
/* Common Styles */
.swiper-pagination-fraction,
.swiper-pagination-custom,
.swiper-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets,
.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-horizontal {
  bottom: var(--swiper-pagination-bottom, 8px);
  top: var(--swiper-pagination-top, auto);
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
/* Bullets */
.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  transform: scale(0.33);
  position: relative;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  transform: scale(1);
}
.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet-active-main {
  transform: scale(1);
}
.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet-active-prev {
  transform: scale(0.66);
}
.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet-active-prev-prev {
  transform: scale(0.33);
}
.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet-active-next {
  transform: scale(0.66);
}
.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet-active-next-next {
  transform: scale(0.33);
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  width: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-width, var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-size, 8px));
  height: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-height, var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-size, 8px));
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-border-radius, 50%);
  background: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-color, #000);
  opacity: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-opacity, 0.2);
}
button.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
          -moz-appearance: none;
       appearance: none;
}
.swiper-pagination-clickable .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet:only-child {
  display: none !important;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  opacity: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-opacity, 1);
  background: var(--swiper-pagination-color, var(--swiper-theme-color));
}
.swiper-vertical > .swiper-pagination-bullets,
.swiper-pagination-vertical.swiper-pagination-bullets {
  right: var(--swiper-pagination-right, 8px);
  left: var(--swiper-pagination-left, auto);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(0px, -50%, 0);
}
.swiper-vertical > .swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet,
.swiper-pagination-vertical.swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  margin: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-vertical-gap, 6px) 0;
  display: block;
}
.swiper-vertical > .swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic,
.swiper-pagination-vertical.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 8px;
}
.swiper-vertical > .swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet,
.swiper-pagination-vertical.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 200ms transform,
        200ms top;
}
.swiper-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet,
.swiper-pagination-horizontal.swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  margin: 0 var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-horizontal-gap, 4px);
}
.swiper-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic,
.swiper-pagination-horizontal.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.swiper-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet,
.swiper-pagination-horizontal.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  transition: 200ms transform,
        200ms left;
}
.swiper-horizontal.swiper-rtl > .swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  transition: 200ms transform,
    200ms right;
}
/* Fraction */
.swiper-pagination-fraction {
  color: var(--swiper-pagination-fraction-color, inherit);
}
/* Progress */
.swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  background: var(--swiper-pagination-progressbar-bg-color, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
  position: absolute;
}
.swiper-pagination-progressbar .swiper-pagination-progressbar-fill {
  background: var(--swiper-pagination-color, var(--swiper-theme-color));
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: left top;
}
.swiper-rtl .swiper-pagination-progressbar .swiper-pagination-progressbar-fill {
  transform-origin: right top;
}
.swiper-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-progressbar,
.swiper-pagination-progressbar.swiper-pagination-horizontal,
.swiper-vertical > .swiper-pagination-progressbar.swiper-pagination-progressbar-opposite,
.swiper-pagination-progressbar.swiper-pagination-vertical.swiper-pagination-progressbar-opposite {
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--swiper-pagination-progressbar-size, 4px);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.swiper-vertical > .swiper-pagination-progressbar,
.swiper-pagination-progressbar.swiper-pagination-vertical,
.swiper-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-progressbar.swiper-pagination-progressbar-opposite,
.swiper-pagination-progressbar.swiper-pagination-horizontal.swiper-pagination-progressbar-opposite {
  width: var(--swiper-pagination-progressbar-size, 4px);
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.swiper-pagination-lock {
  display: none;
}
:root {
  /*
  --swiper-scrollbar-border-radius: 10px;
  --swiper-scrollbar-top: auto;
  --swiper-scrollbar-bottom: 4px;
  --swiper-scrollbar-left: auto;
  --swiper-scrollbar-right: 4px;
  --swiper-scrollbar-sides-offset: 1%;
  --swiper-scrollbar-bg-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  --swiper-scrollbar-drag-bg-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  --swiper-scrollbar-size: 4px;
  */
}
.swiper-scrollbar {
  border-radius: var(--swiper-scrollbar-border-radius, 10px);
  position: relative;
  touch-action: none;
  background: var(--swiper-scrollbar-bg-color, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
}
.swiper-scrollbar-disabled > .swiper-scrollbar,
.swiper-scrollbar.swiper-scrollbar-disabled {
  display: none !important;
}
.swiper-horizontal > .swiper-scrollbar,
.swiper-scrollbar.swiper-scrollbar-horizontal {
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--swiper-scrollbar-sides-offset, 1%);
  bottom: var(--swiper-scrollbar-bottom, 4px);
  top: var(--swiper-scrollbar-top, auto);
  z-index: 50;
  height: var(--swiper-scrollbar-size, 4px);
  width: calc(100% - 2 * var(--swiper-scrollbar-sides-offset, 1%));
}
.swiper-vertical > .swiper-scrollbar,
.swiper-scrollbar.swiper-scrollbar-vertical {
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--swiper-scrollbar-left, auto);
  right: var(--swiper-scrollbar-right, 4px);
  top: var(--swiper-scrollbar-sides-offset, 1%);
  z-index: 50;
  width: var(--swiper-scrollbar-size, 4px);
  height: calc(100% - 2 * var(--swiper-scrollbar-sides-offset, 1%));
}
.swiper-scrollbar-drag {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: var(--swiper-scrollbar-drag-bg-color, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  border-radius: var(--swiper-scrollbar-border-radius, 10px);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.swiper-scrollbar-cursor-drag {
  cursor: move;
}
.swiper-scrollbar-lock {
  display: none;
}
/* Zoom container styles start */
.swiper-zoom-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.swiper-zoom-container > img,
.swiper-zoom-container > svg,
.swiper-zoom-container > canvas {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: contain;
     object-fit: contain;
}
/* Zoom container styles end */
.swiper-slide-zoomed {
  cursor: move;
  touch-action: none;
}
/* a11y */
.swiper .swiper-notification {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1000;
}
.swiper-free-mode > .swiper-wrapper {
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.swiper-grid > .swiper-wrapper {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.swiper-grid-column > .swiper-wrapper {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.swiper-fade.swiper-free-mode .swiper-slide {
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.swiper-fade .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
  transition-property: opacity;
}
.swiper-fade .swiper-slide .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.swiper-fade .swiper-slide-active {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.swiper-fade .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.swiper-cube {
  overflow: visible;
}
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.swiper-cube.swiper-rtl .swiper-slide {
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-next,
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-prev {
  pointer-events: auto;
  visibility: visible;
}
.swiper-cube .swiper-cube-shadow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.6;
  z-index: 0;
}
.swiper-cube .swiper-cube-shadow:before {
  content: '';
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  filter: blur(50px);
}
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-next + .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: auto;
  visibility: visible;
}
/* Cube slide shadows start */
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-cube.swiper-slide-shadow-top,
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-cube.swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-cube.swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-cube.swiper-slide-shadow-right {
  z-index: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
/* Cube slide shadows end */
.swiper-flip {
  overflow: visible;
}
.swiper-flip .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.swiper-flip .swiper-slide .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.swiper-flip .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-flip .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
/* Flip slide shadows start */
.swiper-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-flip.swiper-slide-shadow-top,
.swiper-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-flip.swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-flip.swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-flip.swiper-slide-shadow-right {
  z-index: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
/* Flip slide shadows end */
.swiper-creative .swiper-slide {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition-property: transform, opacity, height;
}
.swiper-cards {
  overflow: visible;
}
.swiper-cards .swiper-slide {
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=view.css.map*/

And the npx @wordpress/create-block@latest app command doesn't add it by default.
CSS & JS are enqueued without the use of wp_enqueue_script
block.json now looks like this (handles are optional):
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 3,
    "name": "m/simple-slider",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "Horizontal slider.",
    "category": "m-gutenberg-blocks",
    "icon": "slides",
    "description": "A simple slider",
    "attributes": {
        "images": {
            "type": "array",
            "default": []
        },
        "speed": {
            "type": "number",
            "default": 1
        }
    },
    "example": {
        "attributes": {
            "preview" : true
        }
    },
    "supports": {
        "html": true,
        "color": {
            "background": true,
            "text": true
        },
        "spacing": {
            "padding": true,
            "margin": true
        },
        "anchor": true,
        "align": true
    },
    "textdomain": "simple-slider",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css",
    "viewScript": ["file:./view.js", "swiper-slider-script"],
    "viewStyle": [ "file:./view.css", "swiper-slider-style" ]
}


yes, has the exact same issue with Swiper CSS, thank you
